# Is Jboss Wildfly 8 certified on AIX?

Tags: java-8, java-7, aix, wildfly-8

A simple question really.

Will JBOSS Wildfly version 8 run on IBM's AIX operating system using Java 7 or higher ?

Is there any official certification to prove this ?

Comment: This is really not a programming related question. Try wildfly's forum: https://developer.jboss.org/en/wildfly instead.

Comment: Thanks, cross posted to there.